# Best Practice for Handling Lots of Graphics in Document

Tags: graphics, compiling

If there is an answer already dealing with this topic, please post. My question is, what is the best way to compile a document when it is filled with graphics?

I am writing a chapter in my dissertation in which I need to use a lot of images. I'm just noticing that the compilation time is now lagging. By the way, the I'm using JPEGs.

Is there way to compile without loading the graphics, maybe leaving just a place holder for each figure?

Thank you.

Comment: `\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}`